# How to fill a 2d array row-wise, back and forth

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to figure out how to sort an array row-wise, back and forth. basically, I need output from my code to look like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/abFixKj]

so far this is the code that I have:

```
static void fill(int [][] a)
    {
        int inc = 1; 
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = inc; 
                inc++;
            }           
        }
        System.out.printf(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    }`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be great to include what output you are currently getting or any issues you are struggling with.

Comment: Please include the output you are getting now or any errors that you are facing. It will help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fill the rows backwards for the even rows

```
static void fill(int [][] a)
    {
        int inc = 1; 
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++ ) {
                // odd row if i%2 is 1, fill backwards (starting with length-1)
                a[i][(i%2)==1 ? a.length-j-1 : j] = inc;
                inc++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint.

- The rows that are **odd** will always be the current counter, `i`.
- The rows that are **even** will always be a product of the current row you're on (say 2), the maximum length of your array (say 6), and subtracted by `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you could try. It utilizes the [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class:

```
public static void zigZag2DIntArraySort(int[][] int2DArray) {
    // Iterate through all the 2D Array rows...
    for (int i = 0; i < int2DArray.length; i++) {
        /* Sort the columns of the current row in ascending 
           order regardless of whether or not the row index
           value is even [ZIG] or odd [ZAG].     */
        Arrays.sort(int2DArray[i]); 
        
        /* If the current row index value is Odd [ZAG] then 
           sort the columns of that row in descending order
           by simply reversing the current ascending sorted
           order. 
        Is the row index number an odd value?     */
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            /* Yes it is...
               Declare a temporary int[] array and 
               initialize it to the number of columns. */
            int[] tmp = new int[int2DArray[i].length];
            /* Reverse the order of the columns in the 
               current row.   */
            for(int j = 0; j < int2DArray[i].length; j++) {
               tmp[j] = int2DArray[i][(int2DArray[i].length-1)-j];
            }
            // Copy the tmp array into the current (odd) row.
            int2DArray[i] = Arrays.copyOf(tmp, tmp.length);
        }
    }
}
```

You might use the above method like this:

```
int[][] int2DArray = {
    {4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5}, 
    {11, 7, 12, 9, 10, 8},
    {13, 16, 15, 18, 14, 17},
    {19, 21, 22, 20, 24, 23}};
    
zigZag2DIntArraySort(int2DArray);
    
for (int i = 0; i < int2DArray.length; i++) {
    String display = String.format("%-30s%-6s",
            Arrays.toString(int2DArray[i]).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""), 
            (i % 2 == 0 ? "[ZIG]" : "[ZAG]"));
    System.out.println(display);
}
```

The output to console window will look something like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6              [ZIG] 
12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7           [ZAG] 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18        [ZIG] 
24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19        [ZAG]
```